# NETStandard.Library и System.Data.SqlClient ошибка: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, .net

Есть большой проект в который я создаю и подкидываю **dll** в определенную папку.

Создаю библиотеку классов `NETStandard.Library (2.0.3)`, внутри использую для подключения к бд `System.Data.SqlClient(4.6.1)`. Пробовал и `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer(3.1.8)`, локально все работает...

Собираю через `dotnet publish`, получаю сборку с зависимостями, когда закидываю полученную **dll** со всем остальным в папку и указываю на нее путь в проекте, получаю ошибку при загрузке из большого проекта:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка и как ее решить? Гуглил, но особо не помогло.

Comment: **Microsoft**.Data.SqlClient и **System**.Data.SqlClient - это разные библиотеки. У вас они где-то перепутаны. Укажите полностью пространства имён в коде.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, проблема не в том что они перепутаны, я в нагетах их отдельно подключал и собирал, проблема в том что на платформе пишется ошибка при загрузке этих dll... почему, пока непонятно